# Block a specific resource, not the entire website

Tags: firefox, url, resources, block

I have a slackware server on LAN with dnsmasq, dhcp etc.
There is also one windows vista computer connected to the network.

I want to block a specific file from one website on the entire LAN or if it's not possible just for one computer.

I thought it could be done with dnsmasq, but it blocks the entire website.
I searched for solutions, but i only found that i can add "127.0.0.1 example.com" in host file somewere in system32 which is not too helpful.

About blocking for one computer. The browser is Firefox, but i don't want to install any addons.

I'd be grateful for any advice on what I should look for or any simple script to write for that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this is to require that the clients access the Internet through a proxy server, such as squid, that supports the ability to block specific pages.